# AKAMAI CCU Fast Purge implementation

Tags: java, akamai

Am trying to implement the CCU fast purge call via JAVA and am referencing this doucument

> https://developer.akamai.com/api/purge/ccu/reference.html

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Entity payload = Entity.json("{  'hostname': 'www.example.com',  'objects': [    '/graphics/picture.gif',    '/documents/brochure.pdf'  ]}");
Response response = client.target("https://private-anon-3f6068ab95-akamaiopen2ccuccuproduction.apiary-mock.com/ccu/v3/delete/url/{network}")
  .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
  .post(payload);

System.out.println("status: " + response.getStatus());
System.out.println("headers: " + response.getHeaders());
System.out.println("body:" + response.readEntity(String.class));
```

here am getting confused with the **objects** and the **client.target** url that needs to be specified.

> " objects': [    '/graphics/picture.gif',    '/documents/brochure.pdf'
>   ] "

Are these objects and `client.target` urls will be unique to my application and the account that is going to be created.?

and also is there any thing that i have to pass in headers for the validation or authentications.?

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- Get credentials for your client using Luna (https://control.akamai.com)

  - Click "Configure... Manage APIs"
  - Select "CCU APIs" in the left hand side
  - Create new collection, create new client
  - Create authorization
  - Click the "Export" button at the top to grab the credentials, including the URL
- Use these credentials and the Java signing client at https://github.com/akamai-open/AkamaiOPEN-edgegrid-java to make the call

There is sample code on the page for the Java signing client showing how to make calls to the system.

Comment: Thank you Kristen, Is this going to be needed for the V3 fast purge REST based Calls of AKAMAI? Can you guide me with the flow that i need to follow for the implementation of V3 REST based purge calls .?

Comment: Here's a blog post on the subject: https://community.akamai.com/community/developer/blog/2016/07/22/moving-to-ccu-v3-now-with-fast-invalidate